# How to store audio file on server?

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$uploadDir = "../audioupload/";    
$uid=$_POST['uid'];
$meeting_id=$_POST['meeting_id'];
$fileName = $_FILES['audio']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
$filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}
if($result)
{    
    $sql="INSERT INTO `audio`(`uid`,`meeting_id`,`audio`) VALUES ('".$uid."','".$meeting_id."','".$result."')";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result1)
    {
        $sql1="select * from `audio` where `uid`='$_POST[uid]'";     
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
    if($count>0)
    {
        $emparray = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {            
            $emparray=array(
                'success' => true,
                'message' => "Audio saved Successfully!",);

        }          
    } 
}    
else 
{
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
   $emparray=array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => "Incorrect Data!",                
            );
} 

    echo json_encode($emparray,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);      
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**this is my code. im creating restful api for storing audio on server.im testing this link with postman tool. it gives me correct json response on postman. and audio saves in mysql database. But it not store in folder named audioupload that is subfolder in another folder. please help me with the same**

Comment: Did you check folder permission, it should be 755 or better try with 777

Comment: your code is vulnerable to **SQL injections** - imagine someone posting a $uid like `'); DROP TABLE audio; --`. you already are using mysqli, so just use parameterized statements to secure your database. also, you are vulnerable for **code injection** - you should use a whitelist to check uploaded files, or someone will send you a "backdoor.php", access it via browser and compromise your whole server.